# Java Inflator & Deflator Issue

Tags: java, string, compression

I need help in understanding an issue that I am seeing in using Inflater and Deflator classes in Java. My requirement is very simple. I want to compress and decompress Java strings.

The issue is that if my string is less than 54 characters then the decompression does not returns all the characters of the strings. My compression and decompression code are as follows:

```
public String compress(String payload) {

        
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
        deflater.finish();

        byte[] output = new byte[payload.length()];
        int size = deflater.deflate(output);

        byte[] payloadArray = Arrays.copyOf(output, size);// I do this to make sure only the compressed data is returned

        deflater.end();

        return new String(payloadArray, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    }

public String decompress(String compressedPayload, int originalPayloadSize) {

        
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(compressedPayload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

        byte[] output = new byte[originalPayloadSize];
        int orgSize = inflater.inflate(output);

        inflater.end();

        return new String(output, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    }
```

My test case is as follows:

```
 @Test
    void verify() {

        final String payload = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves ";// This fails!!

        CompressionDeCompression compressionDecompression = new CompressionDeCompression();
        String compressedPayload = compressionDecompression.compress(payload);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(compressedPayload);

        String decompressedPayload = compressionDecompression.decompress(compressedPayload, payload.length());

        Assertions.assertEquals(payload.length(), decompressedPayload.length());
        Assertions.assertEquals(payload, decompressedPayload);
    }
```

The above test case fails with the following exception:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves 
Actual   :1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves
```

But if I simply add one more character in the payload then it works. For example;

```
final String payload = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves t";
```

In short this does work:
final String payload = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves t";

This doesn't work:
final String payload = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves ";

Can someone please help me understand this issue?

Comment: The assertion didn't come out correctly in the above question. The last space after "leaves" is replaced with a junk character and hence the AssertionFailedError

Comment: That's a strange situation.  It appears to remove only a single, non-alphabet, character.

Comment: I am glad to see that you spelled deflator and inflator correctly. The Java librarians were unable.

Comment: Two problems with this code (and answers) - you shouldn't need to know the original stream size in order to decompress, and `compress` returning payloadArray converted as String might corrupt the data - it should return the `byte[]`. Perhaps you are lucky it works for ISO_8859_1 case.

Comment: Hi @DuncG, my end goal is to store the compressed string in the file and then also read the same compressed string back. Also, the compressed string will be appended with other string via a pipe delimiter. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can suggest, your issue is in this line:

```java
byte[] output = new byte[payload.length()];
```

Deflater class in Java compresses the data into a format that doesn't necessarily result in a smaller size. This is especially true when the data is small or not easily compressible, since it uses the ZLIB compression library, which adds metadata and a checksum to the output (!). For small inputs, the size of this additional data can cause the compressed output to be larger than the input

To prove this option, you may need to call

```
deflater.finished() // false in your case
```

right after the deflate call, which returns true when all input data has been processed and all compressed data has been written to the output, and false - meaning that the output array is not large enough to hold all the compressed data.

I can make an assumption, that it makes sense to have an output array size of at least 2x of input string size in your case (or 100, as minimum), so it should work:

```
public String compress(String payload) {
   Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
   deflater.setInput(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
   deflater.finish();

   byte[] output = new byte[payload.length() * 2];
   int size = deflater.deflate(output);

   byte[] payloadArray = Arrays.copyOf(output, size);
   deflater.end();

   return new String(payloadArray, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}
```

UPD:

For a typical deflate stream, overhead is defined as 2 bytes at the start for the zlib header, and 4 bytes at the end for the Adler-32 checksum, for a total of 6 bytes of metadata; so +6 for the length even for single byte string will be always enough

Comment: Genius @Begging! That was it! I learnt a new thing because of your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can avoid `Arrays.copyOf` by constructor `new String(output, 0, size, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. However as in other comments, converting that binary array to String might not work for all charsets.

Answer (score 1):

I may be just re-iterating your question here.

As mentioned by *@Begging*, I believe it has to do with the *originalPayloadSize* you're providing as a *byte* array length.

Consider the following example from the *Inflater* class JavaDoc.

> *"The following code fragment demonstrates a trivial compression and decompression of a string using Deflater and Inflater."*

```java
try {
    // Encode a String into bytes
    String inputString = "blahblahblah€€";
    byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Compress the bytes
    byte[] output = new byte[100];
    Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
    compresser.setInput(input);
    compresser.finish();
    int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);

    // Decompress the bytes
    Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
    decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
    byte[] result = new byte[100];
    int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
    decompresser.end();

    // Decode the bytes into a String
    String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
} catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    // handle
} catch (java.util.zip.DataFormatException ex) {
    // handle
}
```

This will result in a valid inflation using the *string* you provided.

```
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves '
```

If I change the *output* and *result* byte arrays to *inputString.length()*, it results in an invalid inflation.

```
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves'
```

And, for your code, if I provide an ample amount of space within the array, I get a result with additional 0, null characters.

```java
byte[] output = new byte[originalPayloadSize * 3];
```

```
inflated 159, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves                                                                                                           '
original 53, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves '
```

This appears to be remedied in the example code using, the *[String(byte[], int, int, Charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int,int,java.nio.charset.Charset))* constructor method.

```java
return new String(output, 0, orgSize, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

```
deflated 59, 'x3T0R0V0Q0U0S0W°P°TÈÏKU()ÏWH,(ÈIUÈ/JÌKOUHJÌBÔÄ²Ôb nÉ'
inflated 53, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves '
original 53, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves '
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `compress(String payload)` should be `byte[]` as returning back a String may corrupt compressed bytes - the binary version may not be valid charset sequence. Also you don't want to guess the buffer sizes, you can use any buffer size if you loop over the inflator/deflator code correctly.

As your end goal is to write compressed String to a file, it is simpler to make use of `java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream` and `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` which handle loop over the input data correctly.

This way you also avoid the issue your code has with deciding what buffer sizes to use, and you don't risk corrupting the byte[] as a String. The basic calls to deflate/inflate any byte[] are:

```
public static void deflate(byte[] payload, Path file) throws IOException {
    try(var os = new DeflaterOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file))) {
        os.write(payload);
    }
}
public static byte[] inflate(Path file) throws IOException {
    try(var is = new InflaterInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))) {
        return is.readAllBytes();
    }
}
```

You can combine with `Charset` to permit switching String<->file instead:

```
public static void deflate(String payload, Charset charset, Path file) throws IOException {
    deflate(payload.getBytes(charset), file);
}
public static String inflate(Charset charset, Path file) throws IOException {
    return new String(inflate(file), charset);
}
```

Small test program - as it stands payload is actually larger as a deflated stream due to the overheads, but you can test with longer strings:

```
final String payload = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 one two apple orange banana leaves ";

Path orig = Path.of("/tmp/payload.str");
Path deflated = Path.of("/tmp/payload.small");
Files.writeString(orig, payload);
StringCompressor.deflate(payload, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, deflated);

System.out.println("Size of "+orig+" is "+Files.size(orig));
System.out.println("Size of "+deflated+" is "+Files.size(deflated));

String s = StringCompressor.inflate(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, deflated);
System.out.println("Read from file =["+s.length()+"] = ["+s+"]");
System.out.println("s.equals(payload)="+s.equals(payload));
```

Comment: Note the above requires JDK9+ but is easy to change for JDK8

Comment: Thank you @DuncG! Like I said in my comment earlier the compressed string has to be appended to the other string with a pipe (|) and then stored in the file. For example; A|B|Compressed_Payload|D|E. And then the same line has to be read as well, separated in an array and then the Compressed_Payload needs to be inflated to the actual payload

Comment: You just need to compress the concatenated String "a|b" and unpack the parts once you have it (using CSV with delimiter | or a String split)

Comment: I cannot compress the entire string. Only the payload has to be compressed!

Comment: Your comments show a use case far beyond what you have in the question, and hard for anyone to guess. Its very easy to inflate/deflate a String   - sounds like you need to fill in more details on what you really are trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree with that! I started with some problem and then it went to a different direction. I created another question which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76426235/java-string-read-as-a-byte-array. As per the response I received it seems I need to Base64 encode the compressed payload before storing it in the file. This will defeat the purpose of compression since Base64 encoding increases the length of the compressed payload