# Java String read as a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string, compression, byte

I have a string in the following format:

`A|B|A_VERY_LONG_STRING_THAT_WILL_BE_COMPRESSED|C|D`.

The above string will be parsed with pipe as a delimiter and stored in some array, let say result[].

```
result[0]=A;
result[1]=B;
result[2]=A_VERY_LONG_STRING_THAT_WILL_BE_COMPRESSED;
result[3]=C;
result[4]=D
```

Now the result[2] elements will be compressed using the following method:

```
public static byte[] compressUsingStream(String payload) {

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {

            gzipOutputStream.write(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            gzipOutputStream.finish();
            gzipOutputStream.close();

            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

So something like this:

```
byte[] compressedPayloadAsBytes = PayloadCompressionDecompression.compressUsingStream(result2);
```

Next I intend to convert the rest of the elements in the result[] array to byte as well and create another array:

```
byte[] finalArray = concatAll(result[0].getBytes(), 
"|".getBytes(), 
result[1].getBytes(), 
"|".getBytes(), 
compressedPayloadAsBytes, 
"|".getBytes(), 
result[3].getBytes(), 
"|".getBytes(), 
result[4].getBytes());
```

And then write the finalArray[] to a file:

```
Path path = Path.of(file);
Files.write(path, finalArray);
```

I want to read the same data from the file which I will do as follows:

```
byte[]  allBytesFromFile = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String recordWithCompressedPayload = new String(allBytesFromFile);
```

I separate the compressed payload as follows:

```
int payloadStart = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(recordWithCompressedPayload, "|", 2);
int payloadEnd = StringUtils.lastOrdinalIndexOf(recordWithCompressedPayload, "|", 2);

String compressedPayloadAsStr = recordWithCompressedPayload.substring(payloadStart+1, payloadEnd);
```

Now when I pass the `compressedPayloadAsStr` to a decompression method I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format`

My decompression method is as follows:

```
public static String deCompressUsingStream(byte[] compressedPayload) {

        try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedPayload))) {

            final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(gzipInputStream, stringWriter, UTF_8);
            gzipInputStream.close();
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Call to the above method is `PayloadCompressionDecompression.deCompressUsingStream(compressedPayloadAsStr.getBytes())`

Can someone help with me with retrieving my compressed payload from the file and passing it correctly to the `deCompressUsingStream()` method?

Comment: *Now the result[2] elements will be compressed using the following method:* So how do you know that this binary data won't contain the delimiter? You should probably Base64-encode it

Comment: Compressed data is binary data. No matter if you save it to a file and later load it to a String it will remain binary data. Loading binary data is wrong and will destroy the binary data with a certain probability. so please do never load binary data into a String without proper encoding, e.g. using base64.

Comment: Thank you folks! Question is if I Base64 encode the compressed string will it not expand the length of the string?

Comment: Yes it will but it's a. necessary and b. probably the most compact way

Comment: fwiw I just tried it will a text file of high entropy of size c. 1MB and it actually made it larger (text->gz->base64). Original size 1026025, final size 1041900. If there's lots of repetition in your text, is might be worth it

Comment: Thank you folks! With Base64 encoding the issue is resolved but the compression takes a beating. As an example; my sample payload was 287 chars, compression made it to 222 chars but Base64 encoding made it 296 chars!!

Comment: Yes (see above). You could of course compress the whole thing maybe?

Comment: It would be a tall task since the pipe delimited string with the payload is written to a journal. If I compress and Base64 encode the whole line then it would make it harder to read for any person. We do write some bash scripts on the journal for maintenance purpose which requires our journal should be human readable. Only payload part is ideal for compression as they can get very huge!

Comment: Don't forget, word-processing files, such as LibreOffice spreadsheets are compressed. You might find that smaller to store

Comment: You are using binary data. Is not supposed to be easy to read. You could as well put the base64 strings in a json file if readbility is important.

Comment: @Raj, to clarify the question.  You want to compress a list of _string_ values, and then add each value to a file, delimited, so that you can later open the file, and decompress each value?

Comment: @Reilas basically, I have a string in the format as A|B|HUGE_PAYLOAD|D|E. I need to compress HUGE_PAYLOAD string and append it to the same string. This will result in A|B|HUGE_PAYLOAD_COMPRESSED|D|E. Next I want to store this string in a file. Read it again from the same file. Parse it and decompress the HUGE_PAYLOAD_COMPRESSED to the original HUGE_PAYLOAD

Comment: @g00se I realized that I don't need to Base64 encode it. Because I was already encrypting the payload. The encryption uses AES cryptography resulting in already Base64 encoded string. So basically, the approach was payload -> compression -> encryption -> store it in the file. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A generous thanks to @g00se and @Robert for helping me understand my problem.

Basically, if you compress a string then it no longer is a text. It becomes a binary. And you cannot store binary as a string. If you do then you might lose some data which will eventually corrupt it.

To overcome this, we use Base64 encoding so that there is no data loss. This was explained to me by both @g00se and @Robert.

In my case I was using encryption using the AES cryptography which results in Base64 encoded string. So I merely had to take the payload, compress it and then encrypt it. This resulted in what I intended.

Take a look at this image where I played around with different sets of payload sizes:
[image: Image shows for smaller string we lose compression but we get good compression for bigger strings]